# Serialize generic class using kotlinix.serialization in Kotlin/JS fails

Tags: kotlin-js, kotlinx.serialization

Serializing a generic class with `kotlinx.serialization` succeeds in JVM but fails in JavaScript with message `TypeError: tmp$.serializer is not a function`. Please, see the following Unit Test.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlin.test.Test

@Serializable
data class SerializationTest<T>(val myValue: T)

@Serializable
data class A(val st : SerializationTest<Int>)

class SerializationTests {
    @Test
    fun serializeWithKotlinx() {
        // Succeeds in JVM but throws in JavaScript with "TypeError: tmp$.serializer is not a function"
        Json.encodeToString(SerializationTest(3))
    }

    @Test
    fun serializeWithKotlinxWithBox() {
        // Succeeds always
        Json.encodeToString(A(SerializationTest(3))) 
    }
}
```

How can I serialize a generic class in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1953):

> Unfortunately, this is a known problem and we do not support JS legacy anymore. Please use IR backend if possible

With JS IR it works well, giving the same results as JVM.

Comment: can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)

Answer (score 2):

[See the docs here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/784892467f292dae27d3544148515795cd8eeee8/docs/polymorphism.md#registered-subclasses)

> Please note that this example works only on JVM because of `serializer` function restrictions. For JS and Native, explicit serializer should be used: `format.encodeToString(PolymorphicSerializer(Project::class), data)` You can keep track of this issue [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1077).

In your case, this code:

```kotlin
Json.encodeToString(SerializationTest(3))`
```

uses generics, which is only available on JVM.

You'll have to manually pass the serializer to `encodeToString(...)`

```kotlin
@Test
fun serializeWithKotlinx() {
  val encoded =
    Json.encodeToString(
      SerializationTest.serializer(Int.serializer()),
      SerializationTest(3),
    )
  println(encoded)
}
```

Or use a SerializersModule ([documented here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/784892467f292dae27d3544148515795cd8eeee8/docs/serializers.md#contextual-serialization-and-generic-classes)):

```kotlin
@Test
fun serializeWithKotlinxSerializersModule() {

  val module = SerializersModule {
    contextual(SerializationTest::class) { args -> 
      SerializationTest.serializer(args[0]) 
    }
  }

  val mapper = Json { serializersModule = module }

  val encoded = mapper.encodeToString(
    SerializationTest(3),
  )
  println(encoded)
}
```